# Conditionally Rendering Form Buttons: An Mui Button of Type='submit' Submits Form when Rendered

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a multi-step form using the Stepper component. The continue button switches to be a 'Submit Form' button on the last step.

The problem I was having was that the submit button with a type='submit' would run the forms submit handler... huh???

Does anyone know what could be going on?

I have tried giving the continue button type='button' to avoid auto-submitting. This did not work.

I have tried adding `event.preventDefault()` into the buttons onClick to stop it from submitting the form. This did not work either.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do was provide the **key** property. This resolved the auto-submit issue I was having.

```html
<Button   
  key={activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'finish' : 'next'}
  variant="contained"
  color="primary"
  {...(activeStep === steps.length - 1
                    ? { type: 'submit' }
                    : { type: 'button' })}
  {...(activeStep === steps.length - 1
                    ? {}
                    : { onClick: () => handleStepChange(1) })}
>
```

Comment: Without additional details in the question, this is very unlikely to help future readers. Your solution doesn't really make sense in relation to your problem.